# Hyperledger Caliper Start stream failing

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-caliper

I am using Hyperledger Caliper to benchmark Fabric and I am facing the following errors regarding the caliper workers. I am currently using verion 0.4.0 of caliper

```
2020-11-07T13:06:23.286Z - error: [EventService]: send[peer0.org1.example.com] - #1 - no targets started - Error: Event service peer0.org1.example.com is currently listening
.
.
.
2020-11-07T13:22:52.517Z - error: [EventService]: EventService[peer0.org1.example.com] timed out after:3000
2020-11-07T13:22:52.517Z - error: [EventService]: send[peer0.org1.example.com] - #1 - Starting stream to peer0.org1.example.com failed
```

Logs from docker container :

```
2020-11-10 16:57:20.648 UTC [comm.grpc.server] 1 -> INFO 086 unary call completed grpc.service=discovery.Discovery grpc.method=Discover grpc.peer_address=172.23.0.1:54524 grpc.peer_subject="CN=fabric-common" grpc.code=OK grpc.call_duration=46.965227ms
2020-11-10 16:57:20.659 UTC [comm.grpc.server] 1 -> INFO 087 unary call completed grpc.service=discovery.Discovery grpc.method=Discover grpc.peer_address=172.23.0.1:54532 grpc.peer_subject="CN=fabric-common" grpc.code=OK grpc.call_duration=27.74555ms
2020-11-10 16:57:20.666 UTC [comm.grpc.server] 1 -> INFO 088 unary call completed grpc.service=discovery.Discovery grpc.method=Discover grpc.peer_address=172.23.0.1:54528 grpc.peer_subject="CN=fabric-common" grpc.code=OK grpc.call_duration=1.669585ms
2020-11-10 16:57:21.612 UTC [gossip.privdata] StoreBlock -> INFO 089 [mychannel] Received block [7] from buffer
2020-11-10 16:57:21.619 UTC [committer.txvalidator] Validate -> INFO 08a [mychannel] Validated block [7] in 6ms
2020-11-10 16:57:21.745 UTC [kvledger] CommitLegacy -> INFO 08b [mychannel] Committed block [7] with 10 transaction(s) in 126ms (state_validation=18ms block_and_pvtdata_commit=67ms state_commit=24ms) commitHash=[03a387b92c0f19e18fd7856a50b912eb5ad3c8f88c79f8aa222bc96ff6ed6b6c]
.
.
.
.
2020-11-10 16:57:28.007 UTC [comm.grpc.server] 1 -> INFO 109 streaming call completed grpc.service=protos.Deliver grpc.method=DeliverFiltered grpc.peer_address=172.23.0.1:55012 grpc.peer_subject="CN=fabric-common" error="context finished before block retrieved: context canceled" grpc.code=Unknown grpc.call_duration=6.897965539s
    2020-11-10 16:57:28.007 UTC [comm.grpc.server] 1 -> INFO 10a streaming call completed grpc.service=protos.Deliver grpc.method=DeliverFiltered grpc.peer_address=172.23.0.1:55012 grpc.peer_subject="CN=fabric-common" error="context finished before block retrieved: context canceled" grpc.code=Unknown grpc.call_duration=6.89275949s
    2020-11-10 16:57:28.007 UTC [comm.grpc.server] 1 -> INFO 10b streaming call completed grpc.service=protos.Deliver grpc.method=DeliverFiltered grpc.peer_address=172.23.0.1:55012 grpc.peer_subject="CN=fabric-common" error="context finished before block retrieved: context canceled" grpc.code=Unknown grpc.call_duration=6.897811583s
    2020-11-10 16:57:28.007 UTC [comm.grpc.server] 1 -> INFO 10c streaming call completed grpc.service=protos.Deliver grpc.method=DeliverFiltered grpc.peer_address=172.23.0.1:55012 grpc.peer_subject="CN=fabric-common" error="context finished before block retrieved: context canceled" grpc.code=Unknown grpc.call_duration=6.897066284s
    2020-11-10 16:57:28.049 UTC [kvledger] CommitLegacy -> INFO 10d [mychannel] Committed block [20] with 10 transaction(s) in 143ms (state_validation=0ms block_and_pvtdata_commit=123ms state_commit=10ms) commitHash=[aec792b8877195798b6c5f25a65f9ea10ed32ae93741199ca422311a9bf61766]
    2020-11-10 16:57:28.050 UTC [gossip.privdata] StoreBlock -> INFO 10e [mychannel] Received block [21] from buffer
    2020-11-10 16:57:28.060 UTC [committer.txvalidator] Validate -> INFO 10f [mychannel] Validated block [21] in 10ms
    2020-11-10 16:57:28.120 UTC [kvledger] CommitLegacy -> INFO 110 [mychannel] Committed block [21] with 10 transaction(s) in 58ms (state_validation=0ms block_and_pvtdata_commit=20ms state_commit=9ms) commitHash=[2772cdefd7bb1f2d9a12b6b4ef3cbe7207ca5b8049613e336342e5e23f642642]
```

I dont understand these errors. Any hint for what might causing them?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

A few questions that might help us to help you:

- What version of the Fabric SDK do you bind Caliper to?
- Are you using a gateway based connection?
- Do you have any peer logs available that might also be showing errors?

The SDK errors shown hint that the creation of an Event service failed, which occurs on initial connection to the Fabric network for manager and worker processes as they prepare to interact with the network described in the "network configuration file"

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have posted in the question above some lines that repeat in the container logs of peer0.org1.example.com. The SUT I bind is `fabric:2.1` . Also when running the `npx caliper launch manager` command I include the flags `--caliper-fabric-gateway-enabled --caliper-fabric-gateway-discovery` . The NodeJs version I use is 10.23.0

Comment: OK, two more questions then:
- are you using the caliper image?
- is the network local? (ie the gateway does not require an additional localhost mode flag)

Comment: the network is local and I am not using the caliper image on docker! I installed it locally using npm